# Returning an arraylist and iterating throught the returned list

Tags: java, arraylist, return

Im trying to return an arraylist from the method getNumbers (which contains strings)

```
public ArrayList<String> getNumbers(){

    return (numeros);
}
```

Then by using a searcher im trying to compare between a variable m (which contains the desired info to look for) and the returned list.

```
public class NumberSearcher {

Reader reader = new KeyboardReader();

    public NumberSearcher(ArrayList<Contacto> contactos){

        String m = reader.read();

        for(int i = 0; i<contactos.size();i++){
            if(contactos.get(i).getPhoneNumbers().contains(m)){
                contactos.get(i).display(); 
        }
    }

}

}
```

I have succeded in creating a searcher using this very same style but only when using methods that return String alone.

The problem is its not working. If there there would be a match it should display the contact information but it seem it isnt "comparing" properly because nothing happens.

Comment: Have you considered using a foreach loop instead of a for loop?

Comment: What do you mean by can't compare? Also what does terminating mean here? Does `getEmails()` return a list of Strings? Does that list contain the String m? I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work since `contains()` is using `equals()`.

Comment: Please try to ask questions using a [short self-contained compilable example](http://sscce.org/) as without knowing what is going on inside `Contacto` (for example) it is hard to be sure what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to understand what you're asking here. Your getNumbers method doesn't get called from the second code block, so I don't see where that is relating to anything. It's also unclear what you mean the problem is. Can you try to give us a more detailed description of what is going wrong?

Anyways, I'll try to give you some general advice here, but without knowing the issue it's hard to say how much this will help.

Firstly, it is almost always recommended to have your method's return type as the List interface, rather than a specific implementation (ArrayList, etc). You can specify a return type from within the method but this way they client doesn't need to know what the underlying data structure is, and you are also flexible to future data structure changes.

```
public List<String> getNumbers(){
    return (numeros);
}
```

Secondly, I would probably change the name 'getNumbers' to something slightly more precise - if I see a 'getNumbers' method I expect it to return some numeric entities, not a list of strings. If they are phone numbers then explicity call it 'getPhoneNumbers'.

Though I'm not entirely sure I understand what you asking, I think this may solve your issues:

```
for(int i = 0; i < contactos.size(); i++) {
    Contacto next = contactos.get(i);
    if(next.getEmails().contains(m)) {
        next.display();
    }
}
```

And as an afterthought, is there any specific reason you're only checking string containment? I would suggest that you check case-insensitive equality unless you really do want to find out if the string just *contains* the element.

Comment: Im trying to create a searcher for specific type of queries. In this case the search will only compare "phone numbers". Pretty much what this does is you input a "phone number" and if there is a match it will display the rest of the contact information. And the reason

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
public class EmailSearcher {

Reader reader = new KeyboardReader();

public EmailSearcher(ArrayList<Contacto> contactos){

 while(reader.read() != 'keyThatTerminates')   {
 String m = reader.read();

    for(int i = 0; i<contactos.size();i++){
        var row = contactos.get(i);
        if(row.getEmails().contains(m)){
            row.display(); 
    }
}
}
}

}
```